# Excel If Then with AND Operator - Troubleshooting Formula

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have an set of data that I need to use an IF statement that contain the AND operator and compares rows 1 to 2, then 3 to 4, etc. I am most concerned with the failure in my formula.  It works (generates no errors), but doesn't return The value I expected. I've done searches on here and I have written my formula based on the advice others have posted, but I can't explain the discrepancy in the result.  My data looks like this:

```
+------+------+------+
| ColA | ColB | ColC |
+------+------+------+
|   60 |  160 |   38 |
|   22 |   22 |  -38 |
+------+------+------+
```

I have formulas in Column D, row 1 and 2.

Row 1 formula looks like this and returns the expected value of 5:
=IF(C1>=12,5,IF((C1<=11*AND(B1>B2)),3,0))

Row 2 formula looks like this, but returns a value of 3 instead of the expected 0:
=IF(C2>=12,5,IF((C2<=11*AND(B2>B1)),3,0))

I assume I am doing something wrong with my AND.  As it reads(to me), neither statement should be true and a 0 should be returned. The first part is true, C2 is less than 11, it is -38. The second part is not true, B2 is not greater than B1.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are using your AND incorrectly - don't write it like a grammatical sentence [or even, like most other programming languages], write it like its own function. So, something like IF(AND(C1<11,B1<2),3,0) - but since you didn't describe your formula I can't actually tell what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to use AND():

```
=IF(C1>=12,5,IF(AND(C1<=11,B1>B2),3,0))
```

in Row 2:

```
=IF(C2>=12,5,IF(AND(C2<=11,B2>B1),3,0))
```

[image]

Comment: @user3753404 it is returning what you expect, see edit.

Comment: Yes, this was exactly what I needed. I had attempted this, but failed.  I'll have to work backwards to see where I went wrong, but this gave me what I needed. Thanks to all who posted.

Comment: @user3753404 please mark as correct.  It is something only you can do.  The question will not close until you do.  Mark the one that best answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

The AND function (as well as the OR function) uses syntax that isn't structured like it might "read."  For example, in some programming the "AND" is an operator and goes between two logical tests, like so:

```
 If a=b AND a=c Then...
```

Which is easily "read" as "If a equals b ***and*** a equals c then..."

However, in Excel formulas, AND is a function that requires arguments, which are the logical tests to be performed.  So, the same test above would be written as an Excel formula like:

```
=IF(AND(a=b,a=c), "Both were equal", "Not both were equal")
```

So, if I've understood the purpose of your formula correctly, I believe that your formula `=IF(C1>=12,5,IF((C1<=11*AND(B1>B2)),3,0))` should be written as:

```
=IF(C1>=12,5,IF(AND(C1<=11,B1>B2),3,0))
```

Which would read as "If C1 is greater than or equal to 12, then return 5. If not, then if C1 is less than or equal to 11 ***and*** B1 is greater than B2, then return 3.  If not, return 0."